# How do I append to Text in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am working in a simple program with some button, one text box, and also some combo box.

I am trying to do is when I click button again results have to appear again in text box, and without deleting previous results, for example in combo box 1 i select bmw and in combo box 2 i select germany after i click button the text is showed in text box, and i want to choose again other items, but the previous item (bmw and germany) should stay in textbox. I dont know if I could explain myself.

```
    <StackPanel>
<ComboBox Name="cb1" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="100">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Peugeot"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="BMW"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="GOLF"/>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="cb2" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Usa"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Germany"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="France"/>
</ComboBox>

<TextBox Name="txt1" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="200" Height="100"/>
<Button Name="btnclick" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="50" Height="30" Content="Click" Click="btnclick_Click" />


     public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnclcik_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cb1.IsArrangeValid == true)
        if (cb2.IsArrangeValid == true)
            txt1.Text = "Car:" + cb1.Text + "\n" + "state:" + cb2.Text;

}

private void btndel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cb1.Text = "";
    cb2.Text = "";

}
```

}
}

Comment: wasn't this one deleted ?

Comment: so what is happening right now ? can u see results ? or u cant at all ? or only new text ?

Comment: i deleted this, because to post again to see people, because i need help urgent its my project for tomorrow for school

Comment: first of all that is very bad practice to do and against rules of this forum, secondly if you explain better in first instance you will get a better answer in first instance .. go on .. tell me if ans works ?

Comment: the first result is showed , but when i try to submit again with other detail the previous result are replaced with the new one, i dont want to be replaced, i want to be continued all results successive

Comment: i know its against rules, but i need the code urgent, for that reason i deleted my first post.

Comment: my ans should solve it

Comment: and submitting in school on Saturday ? that's odd ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to append to text rather than set it again ...

Change to this..

```
private void btnclick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cb1.IsArrangeValid == true)
                if (cb2.IsArrangeValid == true)
                    txt1.Text = (txt1.Text + "\n" + "Car:" + cb1.Text + "\n" + "state:" + cb2.Text).Trim();

        }
```

> and there is no postback in wpf. please do read about it, its not just assignment its going to be your learning